# Unable to access shared server space with IP and modified host file (FTP is fine)

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting

I've set up a new shared server space (standard LAMP stack).

I've been able to FTP to it using the IP address, but cannot access it through the browser, eg:

```
https://103.xxx.xx.xx/~username
```

I get a 404.

Same with modifying my host file. I have:

```
103.xxx.xxx.xxx www.mysite.com
103.xxx.xxx.xxx mysite.com
```

but just get a defualt cPanel error (cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi) when trying to access it.

Would anyone know how I can get this working (with the goal of building the site on the server, then pointing the domain name to it later).

Comment: What file are you trying to serve? Do you have the appropriate `DirectoryIndex` directive set?

Comment: Much depends upon the Apache install and how it is configured. However, referencing an Apache web server by IP address often will hit the first site created. This can be a catch-all site or the first site you created. You will need to dig through your configuration files and log files to see what is happening. You will need to check the configuration files using shell or a file manager and the log files using a log file analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of things happening:

- Have you put the page in the document root?  usually public_html.
- Does your host allow temporary URLs xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~user?  This is an option that can be enabled/disabled by the host.
- Have you checked DNS propagation?
- Have you tried a traceroute to your domain to make sure it traces to your host?

Comment: Oh I see that the domain isn't actually pointing there, so disregard points 3 & 4, I suggest the problem is possibly #2.  Have you contacted the host tech support?

Comment: Yep, there is something in the root.

I don't know if the host allows that. They have a 'temporary URL' service that spits out a random series of letters and numbers that can be used. Still, wouldnt changing the hosts file still work?

Comment: You say 'something in the root' just clarifying you don't mean the account root which is usually /home/user, then docs go in /home/user/public_html (or whatever the docroot is).  Why do you even care about the hosts file?  Use the temporary URL until the site is ready, then use the domain.

Comment: Yeah I mean public_html. There's cms files in there, so at the very least it should show the cms error file

Comment: You need to talk to your host.  I have a hosting business and this happens every once in a while.  Generally I remove the domain and re-add it and the problem is resolved.